# Find the index of a value in a list, that is also inside of a string, using the any() function

Tags: python, list, indexing, any

Sorry if the question is a little confusing, but basically I have the following data:

```
useable = ['osc_1_', 'osc_2_', 'osc_3_', 'sample_', 'filter_1_', 'filter_2_', 'filter_fx_', 'lfo_1_', 'lfo_2_', 'lfo_3_', 'lfo_4_', 'lfo_5_', 'lfo_6_', 'lfo_7_', 'lfo_8_', 'random_1_', 'random_2_', 'random_3_', 'random_4_', 'env_1_', 'env_2_', 'env_3_', 'env_4_', 'env_5_', 'env_6_', 'chorus_', 'compressor', 'delay', 'distortion', 'phaser', 'flanger', 'reverb', 'equalizer']
```

I also have a string value: `x = 'filter_fx_formant_x'`

I'm using the following function to return 'True' if `x` contains a value that can be found in `useable`,

`if any(useable in x for useable in useable):`

ex: 'filter_fx_' is in both a *substring* of `x` and a *value* in `useable`.

Now here's my question: How can I get the **index value** of the **item** that *can be found* in a substring of `x`?

Is there a better way other than any()? Am I missing something obvious? Let me know if you can think of anything.

Comment: do You know how any() works?

Comment: Not really, just copied it off of this site :/

Comment: as far as I know it checks if any value is True in iteration and returns True if any is

Comment: oh wait...
Why is it that you find the solution after you post a question :(

Comment: ` for x in destinations:
  for yes in useable:
   if yes in x:
    print(yes)`

Comment: however there is no need to put everything in one line it makes code a bit unreadable

Comment: Yeah, that's a good idea, I've been trying to write more compact code recently and got a little too carried away

Comment: compact does not always mean good (for various reasons)

Answer (score 0):

this You can use if You want to get the index:

```
useable = ['osc_1_', 'osc_2_', 'osc_3_', 'sample_', 'filter_1_', 'filter_2_', 'filter_fx_', 'lfo_1_', 'lfo_2_', 'lfo_3_', 'lfo_4_', 'lfo_5_', 'lfo_6_', 'lfo_7_', 'lfo_8_', 'random_1_', 'random_2_', 'random_3_', 'random_4_', 'env_1_', 'env_2_', 'env_3_', 'env_4_', 'env_5_', 'env_6_', 'chorus_', 'compressor', 'delay', 'distortion', 'phaser', 'flanger', 'reverb', 'equalizer']
x = 'filter_fx_formant_x'

for index, item in enumerate(useable):
    if item in x:
        print(index, item)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is to use `any()`, one way to implement your logic would be by the combination of `map` and `str.contains()`

```
any(map(x.__contains__, useable))
```

**Output**:

```
True
```

if you just want to get the first index if `x` contains substring from the list, you can implement same thing in an `if conditional`

```py
>>mask = list(map(x.__contains__, useable))
>>if any(mask):
    print(mask.index(True))
    
6
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what `next`+`enumerate` allows:

```
try:
    idx, found = next((i, useable) for i, useable in enumerate(useables) if useable in x):
except StopIteration:
    # No hits found
else:
    # idx is now the index of the first item to hit, found is the value
```

If you're guaranteed to have a hit for whatever reason, the `try`/`except`/`else` isn't needed.

Answer (score -1):

It should be like this instead:

```
if (any(substring in x for substring in useable)):
```

Comment: You added unnecessary additional parentheses, and changed a single variable name, changing no behavior at all (admittedly, the original reuse of names was suboptimal, but it didn't break anything). You did not answer the question at all.